# JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0

Tags: json

I am getting the following error when deserializing an object when using the Newtonsoft JSON .NET library. The file itself is created and stores the correct values, but there is a problem when reading the file. Thank you.

> JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: D. Path '', line 0, position 0.

The file is created in .json format and with no format. I tried to serialize and deserialize through Unity Json and everything works, but I need to save a dictionary, and the Unity Json library does not know how.

P.S.
I looked through other articles on this topic, but I did not find a solution to my problem.

My code:

```
[Serializable]
public class LvlData
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public float TimeSpawn {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<int, int> EnemySpawnData {get; set;}
}

public class LvlDataWorker
{
    public void SaveData(string key, LvlData lvlData)
    {
        var path = BuildPath(key);
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lvlData);

        using (var fileStream = new StreamWriter(path))
        {
            fileStream.Write(json);
        }
    }

    public LvlData LoadData(string key)
    {
        var path = BuildPath(key);
        
        using (var fileStream = new StringReader(path))
        {
            var json = fileStream.ReadToEnd();
            
            if (json != null)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LvlData>(json);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    private string BuildPath(string key)
    {
        return Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, key);
    }
}
```

File result:

```
{"Id":5,"TimeSpawn":2.0,"EnemySpawnData":{"0":3,"1":1,"2":2}}
```

Comment: Obviously either your json file is invalid or you are reading it wrong ... Show the contents of that file here. And also show you read the file and call the deserialization. And please post code and error messages as text and not as image.

Comment: added information

Comment: Are you sure, that your "file result" is the output of `Debug.Log(json);`? Because that deserializes fine with Newtonsoft ...

Comment: I'm sorry. I removed this Debug.Log(json) as it had nothing to do with my question. Calls to the Load method come from another class, which first saved the information in the file, and then tries to read it. The structure of the algorithm is as simple as possible, because this is a training program. And she doesn't work.

Comment: Please readd the `Debug.log(json)` and post the exact output of this call.

Comment: D:/Unity/Projects/Test/Assets/StreamingAssets\Lvl0  wtf?!

Comment: Well, that's not a valid JSON string, is it? Don't know anything about unity, but using a [`StringReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.io.stringreader) seems quite wrong here. Because it just returns the string you pass in (in your case your path) and does not attempt to read a file or similar...

Comment: Maybe you want something like a [`FileStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-8.0)?

Comment: Found an error. The problem was that I applied the wrong method in the Load method. I applied the new StringReader(path) instead of StreamReader(path). Thank you very much for your help! Your tips helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the UnityWebRequest class to access the Assets.

Comment: there is access to the folder and the file I need is being formed, but when reading the file, an error occurs that has nothing to do with access to the folder